# How to edit the data in dataset before binding to repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

[context] c# / asp.NET

I have a table in a dataset from query which contains the ranking and the number of stars. I am trying to alter the ranking so that it correctly represents the ties. If five students achieved, 10, 7, 7, 7, 3 stars each, then the rank should be 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, rather than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

The data in table has simply increasing rank in "RowNum" column and I am trying to modify the column data so that it represents ties correctly.

[code with simple ranking - code behind]

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    rpt_BoardList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    rpt_BoardList.DataBind();
}
```

[aspx]

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_BoardList" runat="server">                    
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><%# Eval("RowNum") %></td>
        <td class="center"><%# Eval("username") %></td>
        <td class="center"><%# Eval("starCnt") %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This works fine.

[NEW code with ties]

Here is my attempt to modify the data in the table, but not working....    The table is sorted in descending order of number of stars.  The logic here is remembering the last star counts and number of ties to modify the rank number.   I believe I am having trouble editing the table data.

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dTable = ds.Tables[0].Copy();

for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string strRowNum = dTable.Rows[i]["RowNum"].ToString();
    string strStarCtn = dTable.Rows[i]["starCtn"].ToString();
    int temp = 0;

    if (last_starCtn == int.Parse(strStarCtn))
    {
        tie_counter++;
        temp = int.Parse(strRowNum) - tie_counter;
        dTable.Rows[i]["RowNum"] = temp.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        tie_counter = 0;
        last_starCtn = int.Parse(strStarCtn);
    }

}

rpt_BoardList.DataSource = dTable;
rpt_BoardList.DataBind();
```

============================

This currently returns an error. And no data is shown on the aspx page.

Comment: "This currently returns an error."  **What is the error returned?**

Comment: I am thinking it was the int.Parsing error and referencing the datatable by the column name error (don't know why yet). But I got it working by replacing the field name to numeric index and using tryParse instead of int.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   string strRowNum = dTable.Rows[i][8].ToString(); // RowNum
   string strStarCtn = dTable.Rows[i][6].ToString();  // starCtn
   int temp = 0;
   int starCount;
   int numRows;

   bool result1 = int.TryParse(strRowNum, out numRows);
   bool result2 = int.TryParse(strStarCtn, out starCount);

   if (result1 && result2)
   {
       if (last_starCtn == starCount)
       {
           tie_counter++;
           temp = numRows - tie_counter;
           dTable.Rows[i][8] = temp.ToString();  // RowNum
       }
       else
       {
           tie_counter = 0;
           last_starCtn = starCount;
       }
   }
}

rpt_BoardList.DataSource = dTable;
rpt_BoardList.DataBind();
```